# Sharing source between two Netbeans projects

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an existing Java project in Netbeans (a JSF web application). I'd like to experiment with GWT in a separate project - put pull in source from the original project. Is there any way to share source between two Netbeans projects.

When I attempt to add the source directory from the original project into the new the IDE complains that the source is already part of another project.

Comment: I found an answer here: http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/How-to-build-two-different-jars-using-common-source-and-two-JDKs-in-NetBeans-6-1-td2930895.html

Answer (score 3):

If you're only experimenting then copy the necessary part of the existing project to a different directory. Of course changes won't be synchronized later.

If you'd like to keep both projects alive then create a separate project with the common code, and use it as a library.

Answer (score 0):

Use source control. With CVS, use modules. With Subversion, use svn:externals.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, try moving the source folder outside both project folders. Then add the source to each project. Do not have both projects open at the same time.